# IAuthenticationProvider is deprecated in microsoft-graph:2.3.0, how do I create a GraphServiceClient instance now?

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am upgrading the version of the [msgraph-sdk-java](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java) library in my project. I was using version 1.7.1 but I had some issues with setting conflict behavior when uploading files >4MB. I saw the issue was fixed in the latest version ([see here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/issues/393)) so I am trying to upgrade to version 2.3.0.

I updated my build.gradle file and noticed that now the interface IAuthenticationProvider is deprecated.

> Provides authentication for a requests before it is sent by an HTTP
> provider.
>
> @deprecated use ICoreAuthenticationProvider instead

It says I should use ICoreAuthenticationProvider instead but how do I build a new instance of GraphServiceClient without implementing the IAuthenticationProvider interface?

```
this.graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder()
                .authenticationProvider(appAuthProvider)
                .buildClient();
```

Also, in the README of the library, it says we SHOULD use IAuthenticationProvider, which is even more confusing:
[image]

Comment: Please check if you have also installed the [msgraph-sdk-java-auth](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java-auth) and then give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use whatever implementation you would have.

Whilst it is deprecated, it still works for now.

I imagine an update will allow the ICoreAuthenticationProvider to be used in the GraphServiceClient constructor, but that's not present yet.

Comment: Then they shouldn't have deprecated this yet

Comment: This topic seems to still keep changing. Microsoft Graph .NET SDK v5 was released recenty with tons of breaking changes to v4. Ah! :-(